# How are the weather and vegetation in Kyoto in November-December?

Tags: seasonal, weather-and-climate, kyoto

I am deciding if I will travel to Kyoto in late November, early December.

- How cold is the weather?
- Is there still a chance to appreciate the fall's splendid colors or will trees have lost all their leaves by then?

Comment: @Vince Obviously, the answers should be about late November in general, not November 2013 but that's what the wording suggested anyway. Again, the question never was about a short term forecast, even before my edit. Furthermore, I still don't understand the problem with the trees, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/what-is-the-best-time-to-see-the-lavender-in-france for another example along the same lines.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Wikipedia weather history of Kyoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyoto#Climate) and the [current weather forecast](http://www.weather.com/weather/tenday/Kyoto+JAXX0047:1%3aJA) (as of mid-november 2013), one can figure that between mid-November and mid-December one could expect temperature between 5 and 20°C (low and high of each day), with possible extremes of 0 to 25°C. This is pretty imprecise since it could vary every year, but in 2013 this seems quite accurate.

As of your second question, i.e. whether the trees would have lost their leaves already, while I have never been to Kyoto, I ran a search on the photography website [Flickr with date restriction between November and December 2012](http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=kyoto+leaves&d=taken-20121107-20121220&ss=0&ct=0&mt=all&w=all&adv=1) (I get similar results for 2010 to 2013) and it shows a lot of pictures taken around that time with trees full of leaves (indeed that's pretty nice, by the way). So you should probably be able to see some nice trees while you are there.

Comment: Now, that's a great answer and a clever way to find out! A big +1 from me… but only tomorrow after I get a new batch of votes to distribute!

Answer (score 2):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyoto#Climate) for average weather stats:

[image]