# Provence: Lavender Fields July 10 - 12?

Tags: provence

Similar question here: [What is the best time to see the Lavender in France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/what-is-the-best-time-to-see-the-lavender-in-france) - this is a bit more specific.

We will be in Provence July 10 to 12.

Where can we see the lavender fields? (are there particularly recommended places?)

Found this [where to find the lavender](http://www.provenceweb.fr/e/mag/terroir/lavandes/zones.htm) but I'm not sure if there are any places more worthy than others of visiting.

Comment: You might be interested in the fête de la lavande that's happening all over Provence during the summer. On July 10, it'll take place in Riez and Apt (http://www.fetesdelalavande.fr/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall, lavenders blooms from mid-june to the end of August. So don't sweat it, you should be in the good period for most places ! This year's rains should delay the crops a little bit. In doubt, try to call the tourist office of the places that caught your eye :)

Here's a quick translation of [that page](http://www.moveyouralps.com/fr/routes-de-la-lavande/informations-pratiques-lavande/periodes-de-floraison) which suggests [6 itineraries](http://www.moveyouralps.com/fr/routes-de-la-lavande/itineraire-lavande) to see lavender fields (I left the itinerary titles in French so you can find them easily on the page):

- De la vallée de la Drôme-Diois au Haut-Buëch : blooming is from mid-june/july around Crest. It lasts until the beginning of August in Haut-Diois and Haut-Buëch
- En Drôme provençale : blooming starts mid-june in plains (Grignan, Tricastin) and lasts until mid-July in higher sectors (Vinsobres, Roche Saint-Secret)
- Des Baronnies au Buëch : blooming starts from mid-june in the Buëch valley and from the beginning of July in higher places (Laborel, Mévouillon).
- Entre Ventoux, Luberon et Lure : blooming starts in mid-june around Apt. It continues until August 15 around Forcalquier and Albion
- De la Haute-Provence au Verdon : blooming starts in mid-june around Valensole. It continues until mid-August around Dignes and the Haut-Verdon.
- Préalpes d’Azur et pays grassois : mostly wild lavenders (except the Caussol plateau), blooming starts in mid-june and continues until late because it isn't harvested

Damn I miss my home

Answer (score 6):

I think this a bit opinion based, but the best place would be in the Verdon, just above the Lac de Ste Croix, on the road called "Route de Moustiers", because you can visit the little villages (Moustiers Ste Marie), and of course the Gorges du Verdon.

But it really depends on where you plan to stay, because Provence is big.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Boris answer - this is my most favorite area of France (I live in Paris).

If this helps, I wrote a personal review of the village located close to the lavender fields in Provence: Moustiers-Saint-Marie.

My husband and I travel very frugally and found this village lovely. There's a stigma that Provence can be expensive, but we found it lovely and super romantic.

Please let me know if you have been here before.  Hope my words do it justice:

https://travelista.club/guides/moustiers-saint-marie-discover-a-romantic-village-in-france/